# Rewrite rule for media images

Tags: magento2, redirect, nginx, .htaccess, 301-redirect

we need to set rewrite rule for some images in `Magento 2.2.5` using **.htaccess** rules or **nginx conf**

---

### Example 1

Request Path:

> https://www.example.com//media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/543x403/db978388cfd007780066eaab38556cef/n/u/number1.png

Response Path:

> https://www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/543x403/n/u/number1.png

---

### Example 2

Request Path :

> https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/543x403/db978388cfd007780066eaab38556cef/l/e/legal_slide01.jpg

Response Path :

> https://www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/543x403/l/e/legal_slide01.jpg

---

Here the `l/e/` directories are set according to the first two characters of image name here: `legal_slide01.jpg`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following RewriteRule in the `.htaccess` file inside the `media` folder.
Just add this two lines right below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/(.*)/db978388cfd007780066eaab38556cef/(.*)$
RewriteRule "^.*/thumbnail/(.*)/db978388cfd007780066eaab38556cef/(.*)$" /pub/media/catalog/product/cache/$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This rule will do a 301 redirect, if you just want to serve the imagase with the original URL and do an internal redirect, just remove `R=301` from the rule's options.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have found a more generalized solution for this
`RedirectMatch 301 /(media/catalog/product/cache)/(.*)/(\d+x\d+)/.*/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /pub/$1/$3/$4/$5/$6`

Comment: Great that you have found your solution. If you are looking for more general solution it would be good to specify in future what exactly you are looking for :-)

Comment: Sure, I'll take care of that for next time.